# URL Rewrite query in home directory iis

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get an iis7 url rewrite to work on a query in the home directory. The end goal is to get it to append `index.php` to the beginning of the query string. Everything I try ends in a 500 error. What am I doing wrong?

```
<rule name="post preview fix" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
    <match url="^\?p=([0-9]+)&preview=true"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?p={R:1}&preview=true"  />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to base your rule on the query string, you have to use the conditions.
Something like this should do:

```
<rule name="post preview fix" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^index.php$" negate="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^p=([0-9]+)&preview=true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
```

If the requested page is not `index.php` and the query string matches `^p=([0-9]+)&preview=true`, then the rwrite is triggered.
The `appendQueryString` option is set to true by default so no need to set it.

Comment: If you replace `<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />` with `<action type="Redirect" url="index.php" redirectType="Temporary" />`, do you have the wanted url in your browser? If yes, then the issue comes from your `index.php` file.

Comment: The the problem doesn't come from the redirect/rewrite!

Comment: The homepage of this website is a virtual directory, which is probably what's doing it. The previews actually work just fine before this rewrite, so I thought perhaps writing a rule for preview queries would fix it. Am I s.o.l?

Comment: You are saying that calling `http://website.com/index.php?p=1234&preview=true` works but when you are redirected from `http://website.com/?p=1234&preview=true` to `http://website.com/index.php?p=1234&preview=true` it doesn't?

Comment: No. There is a rewrite rule for ONLY the home directory: `<match url="^/?$" />` `<action type="Rewrite" url="folder/index.html" />`. Reason being, most of the homepage is written in ASP, so we needed a way to implement portions of the website in PHP until we are able to re-write the whole website. When I remove this rule, post previews work perfectly.

Comment: I think I may just have to man up and convert the homepage to php.

Comment: If you put this rule under the other one you should be good to go. The rules are processed in the order they are displayed (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rules_Evaluation)

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the full `rules` configuration section?

Comment: I'm reluctant to do that only because of security issues... posting actual server configurations we've made in order to mitigate hacking attempts. You've been very helpful, though, so I'll mark your answer correct. If it wasn't for our configuration idiosyncrasies it would have worked. I'll just have to convert the stupid thing out of legacy asp code. ...it needs to be done anyway.